# Adding a long content using End of text string(EOT) in terraform is throwing error

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I want to add a content to the file using terraform using a local provider. Here is the example script which I am using

```
terraform {
    required_version = "~>0.13"
    required_providers {
        local = "~>1.4"
    }
}

resource "local_file" "literature" {
 filename = "art_of_war.txt"
 content = <<EOT 
        Hello 
        world 
 EOT
}
```

I am getting the following error  `Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.` .Can you please point what might be error.

Comment: You may want to use `<<-` instead of `<<`.

Comment: Why will question receive a down vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that in your example you were using tabs instead of spaces (or you have it configured in your editor). I recreated your example with using only spaces and it worked. Here's the code snippet that works:

```
resource "local_file" "literature" {
 filename = "art_of_war.txt"
 content = <<EOT
  Hello
  World
EOT
}
```

Note that `EOT` is left-aligned to the same level as `resource`.

EDIT: Actually, it seems there's a whitespace after the `<<EOT`, if you delete it it should work.

Comment: The "extra space" was everything in my case, thanks Marko E!

Comment: Glad I could help!